# process.mainwindowhandle always returning zero

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to start another program from my code and set it to be the size of the screen. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the correct handle of the window, so SetWindowPos() fails. This is on a Raspberry Pi, and the window I am trying to resize is LXTerminal running a Python script.

Code:

```
Process p = Process.Start ("bash", b.command);
    p.WaitForInputIdle (100);

    Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName ("/usr/bin/lxterminal");
    p.Refresh ();
    IntPtr handle = procs [0].MainWindowHandle;
    Console.WriteLine (handle);
    SetWindowPos (handle, 0, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 0x0040);
```

This always prints '0' for the handle, and "SetWindowPos (nil) (nil) to [0,0x1920,1080] 64" after the SetWindowPos has been run.

`b.command` is equal to `-c "lxterminal -e 'python3 ../../../../GameV1.py'"` (but only in this case.) **This code for lxterminal is an example and the program may launch other processes.**

Comment: `lxterminal` accepts a geometry option `--geometry=1920x1080`

Comment: @SushiHangover This works for the terminal, but I may want to launch other types of windows, e.g. a Python process that creates a Pygame window. I really need a way of changing the size of ANY window.

Answer (score 1):

You are waiting for input idle in a maximum amount of time of 0.1s. I sincerely doubt that the process is going to both start *AND* have it's main message loop created in such short manner.

I suggest you use the [**parameterless overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx) instead, so that you'll wait until the process's message loop has entered an idle state - which is when its window should've been created:

```
p.WaitForInputIdle()
```

Quoting the documentation:

> A process is said to be in an idle state when it is waiting for messages inside of a message loop. This state is useful, for example, when your application needs to ***wait for a starting process to finish creating its main window*** before the application communicates with that window.

Comment: Tried this to absolutely no effect, i.e. it still returns zero.

Comment: @ChristopherRiches : Then it's most likely the OS (Raspberry Pi) that doesn't handle window creation or message loops the same way as Microsoft Windows does. If you would've ran this on a Windows machine then that small delay you had would've been the issue.

Comment: @ChristopherRiches : If the process does not close itself to soon, then try to get its `MainWindowHandle` first after a little while - for example when you click a button. If it still returns zero then **A)** There's something else going on with this particular process, or **B)** You'll most likely never be able to get a `MainWindowHandle` out if a process in Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @ChristopherRiches : [**According to this bugreport**](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2009-June/090036.html) `Process.MainWindowHandle` and `Process.MainWindowTitle` always returns nothing. You could try the sample code and se what it gives you, but if it shows nothing for all processes then statement **B** above is correct.

Comment: I've checked and every process running returns zero for its `MainWindowHandle`, so it's probably not possible. Do you know of any other way of resizing a window in C#? Or could updating Mono help?

Comment: @ChristopherRiches : Then that confirms both statement B and the bug report. -- I don't know of any other way, no. All WinAPI functions require a window handle. Have you tried [**EnumWindows**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) or [**FindWindow**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: As of now I have tried both, but both fail to import from the dll with the error `System.EntryPointNotFoundException`. (Code is `[DllImport("user32.dll")]
 public static extern bool EnumWindows (EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);` )

Comment: @ChristopherRiches : Then I guess you're out of options. I have no ideas left.